# oAuth Authentication Twitter - How to login automatically

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth

Hi I need to know how to be able to login to an account automatically using oAuth for twitter on a iPhone. The app should login and present the user the feed for that account.

Comment: You should implement OAuth client in your application. This client will request token from twitter, that token should be authorized by the end-user, and then you can fetch end-user data from twitter and use that data to log him into your application.

Comment: The API you are looking for is this one: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/home_timeline. And when it comes to oAuth, you should probably start trying so that you can ask an informed question. Twitter has a nice starting point here: http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth

Answer (score 1):

OAuthentication requires several stages and you can see these stages outlined [here](http://si0.twimg.com/images/dev/oauth_diagram.png).

I would advise you read about and use and existing oAuth library. A quick search has identified [this](http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2010/09/oauth-sign-in-controllers-for-ios-and.html) one created by Google.